# Is there any way to refine some class' initialize method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
module RefinedHash
  refine Hash do
    def initialize(*args)
      super
      # something here
    end

    def [](key)
      'whatever'
    end
  end
end

class Hello
  using RefinedHash

  def initialize
    h = Hash.new
    p h[:test]
  end
end

Hello.new # => "whatever"
```

As a result `[]` works well and returns `'whatever'` for calls with any key (just for the test purposes to know that our refinement was effectively applied). But, alas, any code in refined `initialize` method won't be executed at all when I instantiate my Hash with the `Hash.new` up there. Am I missing something or is it stated somewhere that `initialize` couldn't be refined as any other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why `initialize` doesn't work. It could be because `Class#allocate` invokes it in some way that bypasses the refinement mechanism? But you can refine `new`, for the same effect:

```
module RefinedHash
  refine Hash.singleton_class do
    def new(*args)
      obj = super
      # something here
      obj
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hashes, Arrays, Strings and other often used objects are a bit special in that they are heavily optimized internally to use a couple of shortcuts. This likely includes that `Hash.new` does not call `initialize` on the new object (not even implicitly) but instead builds the object "by hand" in a faster way.

Comment: `initialize` is `private`, so `Class#new` must call it reflectively (i.e. using `Object#__send__` / `Object#send`), and reflection (currently) doesn't honor Refinements. That, and what Holger wrote. Especially YARV often breaks OO and encapsulation in the name of performance. Rubinius and TruffleRuby do that much less, they don't need to because their optimizers are much better.

Comment: Right! Thanks a lot, guys. I suspected something like this, but wasn’t quite sure how to overcome the limitation. Never before I redefined `new`, and somehow it didn’t occur to me. I guess it’s worth mentioning in Ruby documentation for refinement mechanism (at least I haven’t found it there or missed it when was looking for a clue).